# Code in tkinter stopped working (self)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, keyboard

I have some code here and i cant figure out whats wrong with it. It always gives me the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Intro to programing\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/Jacob/Pygrams/X6.py", line 38, in key
    Ball.down_ball1()
TypeError: down_ball1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

It started giving me this after i changed something but then changed it back. it was working well before.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import time

root = Tk()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.ball = canvas.create_oval(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, fill="orange")
    def key(event): 
        a = str(repr(event.keysym))
        if a == "'Up'":
            Ball.up_ball1()
        elif a == "'Down'":
            Ball.down_ball1()
        elif a == "'Right'":
            Ball.right_ball1()
        elif a == "'Left'":
            Ball.left_ball1()
    def left_ball1(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.ball1, -3, 0)
    def right_ball1(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.ball1, 3, 0)
    def stop_ball1(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.ball1, 0, 0)
    def up_ball1(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.ball1, 0, -3)
    def down_ball1(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.ball1, 0, 3)

root.title("Balls")
root.resizable(False,False)
canvas = Canvas(root, bg="blue", width = 300, height = 200)

ball1 = Ball(canvas, 10, 10, 30, 30)
v = StringVar()
e = Entry(root,textvariable=v)
e.bind("<Key>", Ball.key)

canvas.pack()
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement, and the others like it, are incorrect:

```
Ball.up_ball1()
```

You should change them to this:

```
self.up_ball1()
```